# Why it works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It must be an always toggle div. With no using 'toggle' method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function brFun() {
        $('div').addClass('br');
        setTimeout('$(\'div\').removeClass(\'br\')', 2000)
      };
      setInterval(brFun, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you use the `toggle` method? Can you provide more details to your question?

Comment: I think

    setTimeout('$(\'div\').removeClass(\'br\')', 2000)

should be

    setTimeout('$(\'div\'').removeClass(\'br\')', 2000)

Answer (score 4):

Problem is the delay, as soon as the class is added by `brFun` the timeout will get executed which will remove the class as you are executing both in `2 secs` interval

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function brFun() {
        $('div').addClass('br');
        setTimeout('$(\'div\').removeClass(\'br\')', 2000)
    };
    setInterval(brFun, 4000);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function brFun() {
    $('div').addClass('br');
    setTimeout('$(\'div\').removeClass(\'br\')', 2000)
  };
  setInterval(brFun, 4000);
});
```

```css
.br {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>soemt message</div>
```

---

Without using the second timer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $div = $('div');

    function brFun() {
        if ($div.hasClass('br')) {
            $div.removeClass('br');
        } else {
            $div.addClass('br');
        }
    };
    setInterval(brFun, 2000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92bvnpw4/4/)

Or shorter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $div = $('div');

    function brFun() {
        $div[($div.hasClass('br') ? 'remove' : 'add') + 'Class']('br');
    };
    setInterval(brFun, 2000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92bvnpw4/5/)

Comment: @APJ, has your SO account been hacked?

Comment: @LShetty Ha ha ha. Why do you say so?

Comment: His answer seems right @LShetty!

Comment: @LShetty, I am also wondering. Why do you say his account is hacked?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92bvnpw4/